# How to define a custom keras layer with boolean argument in it's call method?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to TensorFlow. I am trying to use a new block in ResNet. Assume that we want to control its behavior with a flag (called 'first_round') other than 'training' flag. The call function of this block is something like this:

```
class my_block(tf.keras.layers.Layers):
.
.
.
def call(input_tensor1, input_tensor2, training=True, first_round=False):
if first round:
# Do this.
else:
# Do sth else.
```

Now I want to put this block in my ResNet, and I want to use a helper function that produces smaller blocks. It should take an input tensor which has the type 'tf.keras.layers.Input' and constructs a small block containing my_block and ReLU. After reading Keras tutorials, I found that I should use tf.keras.layers.Input to define inputs of a keras layer, but I do not know how to define an input for the boolean argument. The code should be something like as following:

```
def create_block(input_tensor):  # for example: input_tensor=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
input_tensor1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_tensor.shape)
input_tensor2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_tensor.shape)
# ?? first_round = tf.keras.layers.Input(dtype=bool)

x = my_block()(input_tensor1, input_tensor2, first_round=first_round)
x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
return keras.Model(inputs=[input_tensor1, input_tensor2, first_round], outputs=[x])
```

I could not find out how to do the commented line. Is there any specific way to define a boolean input for a keras layer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the `first_round` parameter in the `call` method, you could pass it in the `__init__` method:

```
class my_block(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, first_round):
    self.first_round = first_round

  def call(self, input, training=True):
    if self.first_round:
      # Do this
    else:
      # Do sth else
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The 'first_round' argument gets changed during the training process. So, I think in this way we should manually change this 'self.first_round' attribute in all of the 'my_blocks' of the ResNet during training, and it gets a bit difficult because these 'my_blocks' are defined within another bigger blocks.

Comment: You should think of your model/layer instantiation and the training process as separate. First, you instantiate your tf.keras.Model including different versions of your layers and blocks. Then, you train this model - hence, the `call` method only needs the input data and `training` flag.